# Array copy values to keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$a = array('b', 'c', 'd');
```

Is there a simple method to convert the array to the following?

```
$a = array('b' => 'b', 'c' => 'c', 'd' => 'd');
```

Answer (score 429, accepted):

```php
$final_array = array_combine($a, $a);
```

Reference: http://php.net/array-combine

**P.S.** Be careful with source array containing duplicated keys like the following:

```php
$a = ['one','two','one'];
```

Note the duplicated `one` element.

Comment: array_combine is a bit slow compared to in_array.
array_combine vs in_array vs isset performance test: https://onlinephp.io/c/12411

Answer (score -10):

Be careful, the solution proposed with `$a = array_combine($a, $a);` will not work for numeric values.

I for example wanted to have a memory `array(128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384)` to be the keys as well as the values however PHP manual states:

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

So I solved it like this:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $new_array[$val]=$val;
}
```

Comment: The above is incorrect - your quote comes from the documentation for `array_merge` and not `array_combine`; I even tested it with `array_combine` and the latter value, even in numeric key arrays _always_ overwrites the former one.